# Spring Boot + React: Whitelabel Error Page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I create a React app and imported into a Spring Boot Project in this way:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7e3R.png)

The Spring Boot app starts fine and on http://localhost:8080/TestDX a see my React app.
If I navigate through the webapp I manage to reach the various URLS correctly like this one http://localhost:8080/TestDX/secondo :
[/secondo viewed fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YAyQ.png)

But if I refresh the page or I write by hand the URL http://localhost:8080/TestDX/secondo I get th white label error page like this:
[/secondo white label error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ5Im.png)

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

I used

```
 <BrowserRouter basename="/TestDX">
```

in my React app so where is the problem with Spring Boot?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add HashRouter instead of BrosweRouter.
It will Work.
Me too faced the same issue and its worked for me.

```
    <HashRouter basename="/TestDX">

            your Routes

    </HashRouter>
```